# How to generate SOAP message from a WCF service?

Tags: wcf

Is there any way programmatically or any tool by which i can generate SOAP messages from WCF services ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you mean? WCF uses SOAP to communicate - all WCF messages (except when using the REST based webHttpBinding) **ARE** SOAP messages.....

Something I think I'm not understanding what you're really looking for....

If you need a tool to build SOAP messages to send to a WCF service - look at the `WcfTestClient.exe`  in your Visual Studio Common7/IDE directory - it does that. Works with almost any WCF binding.

Or check out [SoapUI](http://www.soapui.org) for a more powerful toolset to examine and test web services in general (works with WCF's basicHttpBinding).

Marc

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean you want to view the soap messages? if you do, you can try wcf trace viewer.  It comes with VS 2010 developer edition.  If you don't have that, you can try WCF storm, 15 days free trail.

But yeah, like what marc said, if you want to generate soap messages to test your wcf service host, you can use wcftestclient.exe.